# How to add and check for a confirm password to Sign Up via Parse

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, parse-platform

On my sign up page I want users to confirm the password they chose using a confirm password textfield. I am using Swift.

Here is my code for my Sign Up

```
    if(newUser.password != self.confirmPassword.text){


            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up Failed", message: "Sorry, your Passwords were not matching.", preferredStyle: .Alert)


            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
                // ...
            }
            alertController.addAction(OKAction)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
                // ...
            }
            }
```

This is in my `@IBAction func confirmButton(sender: AnyObject)`

Edit:

I am not getting an error, Parse still sign ups users if I just fill out a two different passwords or no password at all.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?


    if (password.text == confirm.text)
        //Continue
    
    else
        //Don't match!

'password' and 'confirm' are your UITextField objects...

Comment: My text fields are usernameField , passwordField and , confirmPassword. My problem is when I go to submit my sign up it doesnt check if the passwordField and confirmPassword field are equal, it just signs the user up.

Comment: Why doesn't your if statement say if(passwordField.text != confirmPassword.text)

Comment: I get an error in xCode saying i need to call "self.passwordField.text" and "self.confirmPassword.text" and even when I do call it my app does not respond to my code. Feel free to show me how you would go about it.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the error you are getting?

Comment: Jacob I am not getting an error, the problem is Parse still creates the user despite my check that the password is equal to the confirmed password, I will try and edit my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I normally do it:

```
func registerButtonTapped() {

        var a = false
        var b = false

        if passwordField.text == confirmField.text {

            a = true

        } else {

            //Passwords dont match
        }

        if(passwordField.text == "" || confirmField.text == "") {
            //alert saying there are empty fields

        } else {

            b = true
        }

        if a == true && b == true {

            //Signup code
        }
  }
```

Comment: now would I add other if statements if I wanted to add more conditions, for example making sure that none of the textfields are left blank?

Comment: @kareem Ok, check it out.

Comment: Thank you I will try and implement this logic using swift!

Comment: @kareem Is my answer not in swift? I apologize, I am still leaning the language.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct but I prefer to do the same with two if statements, the first if statement checks if all the textfields have text in case some textfields are missing we have an alert for the user("Please Enter All text Fields"). The second if statement checks if the passwords are equal and provides another alert("Passwords don't Match"). If all the requirements are meet the function returns true.

```
func validationOfTextFields() -> Bool{
    var a = false
    if(signUpPassword.text == "" || signUpConfirmPassword.text == "" || signUpName.text == "" || signUpEmail.text == "" || signUpStudentMatrix.text == "") 
{
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please Enter All text Fields", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

  if signUpPassword.text != signUpConfirmPassword.text {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Passwords don't Match", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            a = true
        }
    }

     return a
}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code, explain why and how this fixes (in the answer) the question being asked

Comment: I just updated the answer. I am sorry for the lack of explanation, I am new to StackOverFlow.